# Implementation of interactive 3D slicer

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, dynamic, image3d

Being motivated by [this](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/3d-volumetric-image-processing/create-a-3d-slicer.html) I have tried to proceed further to make it an interactive 3D slicer. Here is what I am up to now:

**Code**

```
Knee = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}];
{x, y, z} = ImageDimensions[Knee];
Manipulate[
GraphicsGrid[
{# & /@ {Show[Image3DSlices[Knee, {R}, 1][[1]],
  Graphics[{Yellow, Line[{{Y, 0}, {Y, y}}]}],
  Graphics[{Green, Line[{{0, z - G + 1}, {z, z - G + 1}}]}]], 
 Show[Knee]},
{Show[Image3DSlices[Knee, {Y}, 2][[1]],
 Graphics[{Green, Line[{{G, 0}, {G, z}}]}],
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, x - R + 1}, {x, x - R + 1}}]}]],
 Show[Image3DSlices[Knee, {G}, 3][[1]],
 Graphics[{Yellow, Line[{{Y, 0}, {Y, y}}]}],
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, x - R + 1}, {x, x - R + 1}}]}]]}}],
{{R, 25}, 1, x, 1}, {{Y, 25}, 1, y, 1},
{{G, 25}, 1, z, 1}]
```

And the output is:

[image]

Here, I have tried to find the slice intersections at the *patella*. But in the sagittal and coronal view the intersection points are misplaced. I don't know where I have made a mistake and I want to correct it.

In addition to this, I want two more features to be added to this:
1. I want to view them in full size with the provision to zoom and drag.
2. I want to add 3D seed points by just clicking on any single slice as it can be done in 3D slicer. By the way I'm using Mathematica 11.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the behaviour of the yellow and green they are orthogonal to desired. This seems to achieve desired behaviour:

```
Knee = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}];
{x, y, z} = ImageDimensions[Knee];
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{# & /@ {Show[Image3DSlices[Knee, {R}, 1][[1]], 
      Graphics[{Yellow, Line[{{0, y - Y + 1}, {y, y - Y + 1}}]}], 
      Graphics[{Green, Line[{{G, 0}, {G, z}}]}]], Show[Knee]}, {Show[
     Image3DSlices[Knee, {Y}, 2][[1]], 
     Graphics[{Green, Line[{{G, 0}, {G, z}}]}], 
     Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, x - R + 1}, {x, x - R + 1}}]}]], 
    Show[Image3DSlices[Knee, {G}, 3][[1]], 
     Graphics[{Yellow, Line[{{Y, 0}, {Y, y}}]}], 
     Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, x - R + 1}, {x, x - R + 1}}]}]]}}], {{R,
    25}, 1, x, 1}, {{Y, 25}, 1, y, 1}, {{G, 25}, 1, z, 1}]
```

[image]